# Why I can't place map in item frame to become a map wall

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I placed map in the item frame, they come out like this.

[image: help please]

But I found out on the internet, other players can combine them into a solid map wall. can anyone help to fix it?

Comment: What version of minecraft are you using?

Comment: VTCing as unclear. OP never revisited the site and didn't attempt to clarify the version.

Comment: @MrLemon It's not unclear, though.  He expects the behavior seen in the answer and not the behavior he's getting.  He's not helping us figure out *why* he's not getting that behavior, but I think it's pretty clear what he's asking.

Answer (score 2):

In 1.7.2, Maps, when placed in an item frame, now expand to cover the block, not just sit within the borders of the item frame.

From the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map)

> 1.7.2 - Increased map size when placed on a wall using the item frame.

Now, by simply right clicking to place the map in the item frame, it will sit like this:

[image]

so you can then create a map wall (with some planning and correct alignment) like this:[image]

Comment: He said in the question that he knows this is supposed to happen. He just doesn't know why it isn't happening.

Comment: @WillB. While I haven't specifically stated, the most likely cause of this is that he is using the wrong version. The OP never responded to any queries about the subject, so with the information we were given, this is the best answer that can be provided.